How to show citation number in Bengali (utf-8)?
I am using \usepackage{polyglossia} to write Bengali. But the citation numbers are still showing in Latin numbers. How to make it a Bengali number like ১,[২], ...? I am using XeLaTex compiler in overleaf.
here is the .sty file
\ProvidesPackage{bengali_Style}

% Import polyglossia for language support
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[numerals=Bengali,changecounternumbering=true]{bengali} % making enumaration, citation in bibliograpy in bengali

% Set the main language as Bengali, but allow others
\setmainlanguage{bengali}
\setotherlanguages{english}

% Set custom fonts for Bengali with bold and italic variants
\newfontfamily\bengalifont[
    Script=Bengali,
    BoldFont=Ruposhi Bangla UI Uni Bold.ttf,
    ItalicFont=Ruposhi Bangla UI Uni Bold Italic.ttf,
    BoldItalicFont=Ruposhi Bangla UI Uni Bold Italic.ttf
]{Ruposhi Bangla UI Uni.ttf}

% Set custom fonts for English (no need for Script=english)
\newfontfamily\englishfont[
    BoldFont=SwanseaBold-D0ox.ttf,
    ItalicFont=SwanseaItalic-AwqD.ttf,
    BoldItalicFont=SwanseaBoldItalic-p3Dv.ttf
]{Swansea-q3pd.ttf}

% Set the default size of the document text to normalsize
\AtBeginDocument{%
    \normalsize
}

% bullte point rendering
\renewcommand\labelitemi{\normalsize\textemdash} % Use an en-dash as a bullet


% Mapping for Arabic numerals to Bengali numerals using \ifcase
\newcommand{\mybengalinumber}[1]{%
  \ifcase#1 ০% 0
  \or ১% 1
  \or ২% 2
  \or ৩% 3
  \or ৪% 4
  \or ৫% 5
  \or ৬% 6
  \or ৭% 7
  \or ৮% 8
  \or ৯% 9
  \fi
}
...

and the main.tex is something like this
\documentclass{article}
% custom Bengali section package
\usepackage{bengali_Style}
\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{
 a4paper,
 total={170mm,257mm},
 left=20mm,
 top=20mm,
 }
 \usepackage{url}
 % For references
\usepackage{cite}
 
\title{রচনার নামঃ বাংলা ভাষা}
\author{লেখকঃ উইকিপিডিয়া}
\date{১২ই ভাদ্র ১৩২১ বঙ্গাব্দ}

\begin{document}
\maketitle


\input{_secs/first_sec}
\input{_secs/second_sec}

%%% Bibliography %%%
\bibliographystyle{plain} 
\bibliography{reference}

\end{document}



As always on the site, please provide the code you used to get this output. You can simplify it by showing just the first section and the bibliography, and removing any packages or settings that are not needed to reproduce the issue.

u r right, modified the question

This is much better, thank you. However, it can be more minimal, now there are \input statements for files we don't have, and the code is divided in two files where it could be just one. Also the ... at the end of the first part would cause the code to fail. Please make it such that we can just copy one piece of code into some file, run xelatex somefile (and bibtex and xelatex again) and then we get the output that you show. Relatedly, maybe you can find more common fonts that people may already have installed (at least for the English part), that would make it easier to reproduce.

That said, https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/issues/104 seems related, maybe you can use some of the ideas there.

this solved the problem. Thanks, writing as details.

Adding the following resolved the problem:
// .sty
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\bibcite}{#2}{\mybengalinumber{#2}}{}{}

